# Mybatis, insert in Oracle with sequence id

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I have tried with this:

```
<insert id="insertPersonalizacionUsuario" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="param1.id" keyColumn="id">
    INSERT INTO dsk_prop_personali (idpersonalizacion, idusuario, valor, centro) 
    VALUES (#{param1.idPersonalizacion}, #{param1.idUsuario}, #{param1.valor}, #{param2})
```

And with this:

```
<insert id="insertPersonalizacionUsuario" useGeneratedKeys="true"          keyProperty="param1.id" keyColumn="id">
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int"> 
         SELECT id.nextVal from dual 
    </selectKey> 
    INSERT INTO dsk_prop_personali (id, idpersonalizacion, idusuario, valor, centro) 
    VALUES (#{id}, #{param1.idPersonalizacion}, #{param1.idUsuario}, #{param1.valor}, #{param2})
```

But not working. Thanks

Comment: What is the error message? In the second version the mybatis part is fine your SQL is wrong though. It should be `select sequenceName.nextVal() from dual`

Comment: You are also not passing the param to the mybatis.

Comment: Please, add oracle version. since  Oracle 12c, you could have something like Autoincremental.

Comment: The version is 11.

Comment: this: select id.nextVal() from dual give me error. Error selecting key or setting result to parameter object

Answer (score 5):

You must add the `order` attribute with `BEFORE` value to  `<selectKey>`  element. In your case you are using an Oracle database which  until version `12c` (review your case) it doesn't have auto-generated column types and works with a sequence is not related with your column by the rdbms.

If you take a look the [documentation reference](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) there is a section which explains your case:

> MyBatis has another way to deal with key generation for databases that
>   don't support auto-generated column types, or perhaps don't yet
>   support the JDBC driver support for auto-generated keys.
>
> Here's a simple (silly) example that would generate a random ID
>   (something you'd likely never do, but this demonstrates the
>   flexibility and how MyBatis really doesn't mind):
>
> ```
> <insert id="insertAuthor">   
>     <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
>         select CAST(RANDOM()*1000000 as INTEGER) a from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1  
>    </selectKey>   
>
>    insert into Author
>     (id, username, password, email,bio, favourite_section)   
>      values
>     (#{id}, #{username}, #{password}, #{email}, #{bio}, #{favouriteSection,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
> ```
>
> In the example above, the **selectKey statement would be run first**, the
>   Author id property would be set, and then the insert statement would
>   be called. This gives you a similar behavior to an auto-generated key
>   in your database without complicating your Java code.

So, to be sure the selectKey statement will run first, you would need to use the Order attribute with `BEFORE` value, the attribute is explained very good after this example in the reference documentation:

> **order** This can be set to BEFORE or AFTER. If set to BEFORE, then it
>   will select the key first, set the keyProperty and then execute the
>   insert statement. If set to AFTER, it runs the insert statement and
>   then the selectKey statement – which is common with databases like
>   Oracle that may have embedded sequence calls inside of insert
>   statements.

Therefore, you must match your `keyProperty` value with the insert param as you have done (`keyProperty="id"` will be the Param in insert statement:`#{id}`), and specify the `resultType` as int so it is a numeric sequence.

Otherwise, you must do your select using the sequence id name, in your case be sure your sequence is called id (because you are using `id.NEXTVAL`):

```
 SELECT YOUR_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thanks but I can not make it work
<insert id="insertPersonalizacionUsuario" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="param1.id" keyColumn="id">
        <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
      SELECT id.nextVal() from dual
    </selectKey>
        INSERT INTO dsk_prop_personali (id, idpersonalizacion, idusuario, valor, centro) 
        VALUES (#{id}, #{param1.idPersonalizacion}, #{param1.idUsuario}, #{param1.valor}, #{param2})
   </insert>

ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

```
<insert id="insertAuthor">   
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
        select MYSEQUENCE.nextval from dual  
   </selectKey>   

   insert into Author
    (id, username, password, email,bio, favourite_section)   
     values
    (#{id}, #{username}, #{password}, #{email}, #{bio}, #{favouriteSection,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```